# What are concrete indices

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

In relation to elasticsearch, what are concrete indices.

The elasticsearch docs mention them hundreds of times, but I can't find a definition anywhere.

### For example:

#### [count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-count) - allowNoIndices:

- Whether to ignore if a wildcard indices expression resolves into no ~*concrete indices*~.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A concrete index is simply a real index that is stored in Elasticsearch and that you can list with a [`/_cat/indices`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html) command such as

```
 curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
```

As you probably know, when searching you can either specify:

1. one concrete index: `/my_index/_search`
2. more than one concrete indices: `/my_index1,my_index2/_search`
3. one alias: `/my_alias/_search`
4. more than one aliases: `/my_alias1,my_alias2/_search`
5. an index wildcard: `/my_*/_search`

In cases 1 and 2, you specify concrete indices, i.e. indices that you would see listed by the `/_cat/indices` command above.

In cases 3 and 4, the alias(es) you specify will resolve to concrete indices, so that in the end if `my_alias` is an alias for `my_index1` and `my_index2`, then 3. is equivalent to 2.

In case 5, it's just a shortcut to not have to list all concrete indices whose name starts with the prefix `my_`. You often use that when you have time-based indices, such as `logstash-2015*` for all logstash indices of the year 2015.

To sum it up, a concrete index is an index that [you have created](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) one way or another and that will show when listing all indices of present in your Elasticsearch instance.